# Flink operator design advice

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, system-design

I have some data that I need to process and aggregate, ideally avoiding data skew but I am unsure how to design a topology that would do so.

As an example, my data would look like this:

```
struct Object {
    int a
    int b
    int c
}
```

Now, the goal is to aggregate data via combinations of int a and b, and determine how many times int c has occured. So as example, say we have data:

```
Object(1,2,3)
Object(1,2,1)
Object(1,4,1)
Object(1,4,1)
```

The final goal is to look like

```
Result(1,2,{3:1, 1:1}) // Key 3 and 1 both occured only once
Result(1,4,{1:2})     // Key 1 has occured twice in the datastream
```

My current approach, is to KeyBy a Tuple2 of int a and b, then use a session window to aggregate the occurences of int c and return output. I am using a session window because the same int a and b combinations happen during similar time frames, one can understand this as an user's action.

However, this presents a dataskew problem as I am struggling to distribute workload evenly. Is there a better design to approach this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know **for sure** that data skew is a problem, then you could first do a count of occurrences using all three values as the key, and then do a second aggregation of those results with a keyBy of just the first two values.

Though this would only help if you know that you're getting a reasonable number of occurrences for each unique key from all three values.

Comment: Yes I have already encountered data skew. I see that your solution is to further increase variety via combining all three values, then aggregate? Can you help explain how that would help with reducing data skew, since I still see that this process aggregates by the first two values again. Thanks!

Comment: As an extreme example, if you have <A, B, C> occurring 1M times, and <A, B, D> occurring 1M times, the first step would use two groups and give you single records with <A, B, C, 1M> and <A, B, D, 1M>. Then when you key by <A, B>, you'd only be processing 2 records, not 2M records.